# What is the difference between boolean = true and just boolean

Tags: java, boolean, operators

I'm doing a practice question which is:

We have a loud talking parrot. The "hour" parameter is the current hour time in the range 0..23. We are in trouble if the parrot is talking and the hour is before 7 or after 20. Return true if we are in trouble.

parrotTrouble(true, 6) → true
parrotTrouble(true, 7) → false
parrotTrouble(false, 6) → false

My code is:

```
`public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
 if ((talking = true) && (hour < 7 || hour > 20)){
 return true;
 }
 else
 return false; 
}`
```

The correct answer is:

```
public boolean parrotTrouble(boolean talking, int hour) {
          return (talking && (hour < 7 || hour > 20));
          // Need extra parenthesis around the || clause
          // since && binds more tightly than ||
         // && is like arithmetic *, || is like arithmetic +

}
```

I am wondering what is the difference between talking = true and just talking.

Comment: you assign true to talking in the if statement and it´s resolved to `(talking = true) == true`

Comment: The first example is already buggy; it will affect `true` to boolean variable `talking`, and as such the condition will always be true. The author probably meant `talking == true`, but then just `talking` is enough

Comment: it should (talking == true) or just (talking) your are doing assign talking = true

Answer (score 7):

`talking = true` assigns true to `talking` and returns true.

`if (talking == true)` is the same as `if (talking)`, since both return true.

Answer (score 1):

in Java , sign equal represents assignments, double equal represents comparison.

In your case you are assigning instead of comparing.

Answer (score 0):

When you just use `talking`, it will have same value which is passed as parameter to `parrotTrouble` method. So value changes as per input.

Whereas `talking = true` is an assignment which will always evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 0):

In java if statement requires result of if condition = true // `if(condition)`
to be able to execute code inside curly bracket // `{}`
=> this true you can assign directly i.e `if(true)`
or it can generated as result of condition i.e `if(val==true)` 
now in your case
when you put `talking = true` it assign true to talking and return true
and in other code use talking directly which contains value true so it returns true